# Object mapping to database with hibernate issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've just started learning hibernate with databases and faced with problem in the start. I can't make mapping of object to database.
[Log of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3aqG.png)

As I've understood, system didn't know which database I wana use.

[My Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x86LY.png)

[My main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j2N3.png)

[And hibernate.cfg.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODgHy.png)

Sorry for this f***n reference, I can't public pictures due to the fact that StackOwerflow rebooted my account when I've changed my mail.

Comment: You have not selected any database, it says right there in the logs. So make sure you enter the complete address to your database like so, `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<your_database_name_goes_here>`

Comment: you should choose a database, it seems from your logs that your are not using any database schema to connect to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_db_schema`, and please do not post pictures of the logs it is preferable to provide the stack trace in text format :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems seems in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`. You need to add your schema name in there too. So change this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
```

to this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<your_schema_name>
```

Also, consider adding your code in textual format and not pictures next time.

Comment: Yep, problem was in my config, thanks!!!)))) Why pictures? Because if a posted code I had message, that too much code, write more description.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the way to my `hibernate.cfg.xml.` file.
I've created resources package and moved `hibernate.cfg.xml.` there.